# How to rotate MKMapView and keep the Annotation and the view don't rotate?

Tags: iphone, annotations, rotation, mkmapview

I am making an MKMapView that shows the user's current location.
I want to rotate the map like the Google Maps App without rotating the annotations. Im using the following code

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{
     mapView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1*newHeading.magneticHeading*3.14159/180)};
```

but the whole view is rotated like this image.
[The image of the problem in my app](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22880687/Screenshot.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically need to apply a the same transform to all annotation views but with negative angle, i.e.

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) 
{
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
    [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle)];
}
```

If you're planning to add more annotations you should place the same code in `mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:` too:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    for (MKAnnotationView* annotationView in views) 
    {
        [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle)];
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the code in - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views, the rotation in applied on heading change is enough (testing it on a device right now! :) )

Answer (score -1):

All the annotations and callouts that are shown on an MKMapView are subviews of MKMapView so if you rotate the container view all of its subviews are also going to be rotated.

Comment: yes, that is the point. In the controller, I only add the mapView as subview. When I put the annotations on the mapView, and transform the mapView. All content will be rotated, including the Google logo.

Comment: sorry did i miss something? My answer basically means there isnt a way of doing it that is supported currently in the sdk

Comment: you add mapview as subview but all the other things in the map are added as subview to the map. You dont do it but thats how its implemented at the back end.