# Default User Location Annotation with Heading

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager, mkannotationview, mkuserlocation

I know. I found this question as well: [Turning user location annotation with heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158812/turning-user-location-annotation-with-heading)

Sadly, what I'm trying to do here is much simpler (or so I thought) and that one is bit too complicated for me. I would like to show the default blue dot with the heading. However, I do not want the map to rotate automatically, but rather only the blue dot rotates, so the tracking mode does not work the way I want it to. What I want to do is what the Transit app uses.

Can anyone give me a tutorial on how to accomplish this? I've spent a good amount of time trying things out and still couldn't get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own blue dot image instead of using default one for map. That image should be with arrow. and you can find out heading with corelocation methods and rotate image in that way.

Comment: So, in other words, there are no easy way to do this with the default blue dot? Well, that's disappointing. I guess I'll just create a custom image as you suggested then. Thanks!